# Mongodb add an object to an object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Say I have a mongodb document I'm trying to update. The schema is level1 (object)> level2  (object) > "objects".
If I want to add another object to the end, what is the method to do that? Do I use findoneandupdate?
I'm trying to append an object to an object
As of right now, it overwrites whatever is in the object

```
await base.findOneAndUpdate({ baseURL: contentObject.basURL },
                    {
                        "links.subPageURLs": {
                            [contentObject.subPage]: contentObject.links.subPageurls[contentObject.subPage]
                        },
                        "content.subPageContent": {
                            [contentObject.subPage]: contentObject.content.subPageContent[contentObject.subPage]
                        }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { upsert: true }, (err, doc) => {
                        console.log(err)
                        db.close()
                    })
```

My final product would look something like this:

```
        subPages: {
            contactus: ["www.example.com", "www.website.com/subpage", "etc..."],
            aboutus: ["www.example.com", "www.website.com/subpage", "etc..."],
            news: ["http://news.example.com", "www.newsexample.com", "etc..."]
        }
    }
```

Then if i had another page to add, i would add it to the subPages object
`login: ["login.example.com", "signup.example.com"]`

Comment: Show a sample document and what the result should look like.

Answer (score 0):

To append an object to another object you can try to do this.

```
const a = { name:`Bob`, age:30 }
const b = { gender:`M`, age:45 }

const c = { ...a, ...b } //this will merge "a" with c

console.log(c) // will print { name:`Bob`, age:45, gender:`M` }
```

So it will work like that all properties in right object will overridden by left object and the left object properties does n't exists in right object will be appended.